# Scrolling in my app is really not smooth

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, lag

I made an android app that plays sounds when clicking the button. These sounds can be also shared via messenger. All of these buttons (their look and position) are specified in activity_main.xml. The problem is, when I scroll up or down in my app, it looks terrible, because it's not smooth and my app seems to be laggy.

Here's my code with some buttons and imageviews for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/r1">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/sound1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundbuttons"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sound3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sound3"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/sound2"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/sound2"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundbuttons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sound1"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sharebutton"
        android:id="@+id/share_button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sound1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sound1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sharebutton"
        android:id="@+id/share_button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sound2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sound2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sound2" />
```

There are in total **25 buttons and 25 imageviews** in my activity_main that look like this. All of these imageviews are based on one file (**sharebutton.jpg**).

**EDIT:**
Main Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

private MessengerThreadParams mThreadParams;
private boolean mPicking;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button s1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
    Button s2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound2);
    findViewById(R.id.share_button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            onMessengerButtonClicked1();
        }

    });

    findViewById(R.id.share_button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            onMessengerButtonClicked2();
        }

    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_PICK.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        mThreadParams = MessengerUtils.getMessengerThreadParamsForIntent(intent);
        mPicking = true;
    }

    s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPause();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a1);
            mp.start();
        }

    });


    s2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPause();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a2);
            mp.start();
        }

private void onMessengerButtonClicked1() {
    // The URI can reference a file://, content://, or android.resource.
    Uri uri =
            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/raw/" +R.raw.a1);

    ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
            ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "audio/mpeg")
                    .setMetaData("{ \"audio\" : \"a1\" }")
                    .build();

if (mPicking) {
    MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(this, shareToMessengerParams);
    } else {
    MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
            shareToMessengerParams);
    }
}
private void onMessengerButtonClicked2() {
    Uri uri =
            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/raw/" +R.raw.a2);

    ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
            ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "audio/mpeg")
                    .setMetaData("{ \"audio\" : \"a2\" }")
                    .build();

    if (mPicking) {
        MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(this, shareToMessengerParams);
    } else {
        MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
                this,
                REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
                shareToMessengerParams);
    }
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: on emulator? or on real mobile device?  emulator are slow. run it with higher memory

Comment: On real mobile device, I don't use emulator because I have to use messenger buttons to check if they works

Comment: difficult to say, I would say the code needs to be looked at. xml doesn't provide us with much info and if your code in your activity isn't a problem. it is your device or connection if it's retrieving data from the net.

Comment: I've added code of the MainActivity class. Hope it'll help find the problem.

Comment: It looks like buttons require sounds files. There isn't really any buffer between memory and the app.  If I imagine this, the whole audio is loaded together in the background when you really want to load the specific audio file when the button is clicked.   you may want to have a manager to manage this or methods, like onDestroy, onStop, etc.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Above is a general outline that can be used in broad areas including your situation.

As for your code you can implement the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mp.onResume();
        // Setup the player
        mp.resume();
    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp != null)

                {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
}
```

If it helps, use logs to help you see the lifecycle

```
try{
    if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
       Log.d("TAG------->", "player is running");
       mp.stop();
       Log.d("Tag------->", "player is stopped");
       mp.release();
       Log.d("TAG------->", "player is released");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
   //Throw the error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! Sorry for that question, but I'm begginer. Can you please show me your code implemented into my code? Only reason for that is, when I try to do it by myself, android studio marks the
       `mp.*onResume*();
        // Setup the player
        mp.*resume*();` as error. By the way, where can I connect the mp3 file to the button? in my code I did it by using `mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a1);` where a1 was mp3 file. I would be very grateful if you could explain me that.

Comment: I found that loading all files together is really the reason why my app is laggy, but I still don't know how to implement your method into my code. Can you please help me with this?